# I'm getting an error when I turn on string Unicode encoding

Tags: c#, wpf

So, I'm making a program that reads from the Spanish dictionary. It grabs a random word. I need to turn on Unicode for a string because there will be characters like "é" and that, obviously requires encoding the string differently. When I turn on Unicode for the `string[]` it gives me this error message:

```
    System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'WordADay.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '9'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=4
  LinePosition=9
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
       at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at WordADay.App.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\WordADay\WordADay\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
       Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
       Source=WordADay
       StackTrace:
            at WordADay.MainWindow.newWord() in C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\WordADay\WordADay\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 132
            at WordADay.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\WordADay\WordADay\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 33
       InnerException:
```

Which, by the way, is completely wacky for me and I can't understand it. Just asking, what does this mean when coming from this code?:

```
        #region Setup
        Random word = new Random();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(dictionarypath, Encoding.Unicode);
        int randomword = word.Next(1, lines.Count());

        string[] excludedlines;
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);
        }
        excludedlines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        string chosenWord = lines[randomword];
        #endregion

        #region Logic
        if (excludedlines.Count() == 58110)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path, "");
        }
        if (excludedlines.Contains(chosenWord))
        {
            while (excludedlines.Contains(chosenWord))
            {
                randomword = word.Next(58110);
                chosenWord = lines[randomword];
            }

            File.AppendAllText(path, chosenWord + Environment.NewLine);
            excludedlines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            label1.Content = chosenWord;

        }
        else
        {
            File.AppendAllText(path, chosenWord + Environment.NewLine);
            excludedlines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            label1.Content = chosenWord;
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: why don't you try stepping through it?

Comment: @pquest stepping though did not work.

Comment: I didn't mean that would fix it. Actually take a look around at the values of the variables and whatnot and see if you can figure out what is wrong. You should always do that before asking a question on here.

Comment: What is the code at MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 132?

Comment: What the heck do you mean by "turn on Unicode for the string[]"? Strings in .NET are *already* Unicode.

Comment: @JoeWhite why are the special characters � then?

Comment: @EthanArterberry Probably because you used the wrong encoding when you read the string from a file. If you haven't yet, read Jon Skeet's article on [Unicode and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx) and Joel Spolsky's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two lines could easily throw an index out of range exception:

```
        randomword = word.Next(58110);
        chosenWord = lines[randomword];
```

Surely the following would make more sense:

```
        randomword = word.Next(lines.Length);
        chosenWord = lines[randomword];
```

Also, the following line:

```
        int randomword = word.Next(1, lines.Count());
```

should probably be

```
        int randomword = word.Next(lines.Length);
```

In your version, the word at `lines[0]` will never be chosen randomly, which looks wrong.

Comment: This still doesn't work with Unicode, my program doesn't give an error, but doesn't start.

Comment: If that's true, then you should debug it in visual studio and [break when exceptions are thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx).  Then figure out the exact line where the problem is occurring, and debug it.  If you're still not sure what is happening you can post the details here.